# Blazor doesn't detect variable change if it occurs on a separate Thread

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

In my blazor, I put:

```
@if (cat.IsMeowing)
{
  <div>Cat is meowing!!!</div>
}
```

In my `Cat` class, I put this:

```
public bool IsMeowing {get; set;} = false;
public void Meow()
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
                await Task.Delay(3000); // Cat takes a deep breath
                IsMeowing = true; // MEOW!!!!!!!
    });
}
```

The behaviour I want is that when I call Meow, there is a delay, and then it sets the variable which causes the Div to appear. However, blazor does not seem to notice that the variable has updated when it is updated via a closure from another thread.

If I remove the task, and just put the delay and the IsMeowing=true, then blazor notices it and updates correctly.

Is there a way I can get around this without implementing a callback?

Ultimately, I want to create a class that when a method is invoked on it, sets a variable after 3 seconds that blazor notices. Imagine for example that I want to show a message "This operation is taking a while..." if 3 seconds elapses while I'm doing other intensive work, so I can set one of these going, start doing my intensive work, and after my intensive work is done cancel it. If the intensive work took <3 seconds nothing would happen, and if it took more than 3 seconds the message would appear via the blazor if.

Comment: it is awaited, so the code is basically, `timer.Start();` > `await longRunningTask()` > `timer.Stop();` and the timer is this class, that waits 3 seconds then sets a variable that blazor can detect.

Comment: My code is blazor server

Comment: On the server you can use Task.Run() but do `await` it.

Comment: I cannot await it because that will block the thread. It is supposed to count up to 3 seconds in the background and display the message. The problem is that Blazor is not detecting the variable change. I am wondering if I can fix that without a callback.

Comment: `await` does not block the Thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The task you create is something external, hence [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/rendering?source=recommendations&view=aspnetcore-7.0#receiving-a-call-from-something-external-to-the-blazor-rendering-and-event-handling-system) applies. This is one of the cases when StateHasChanged() must be called. To do that:

Main.razor:

```
@implements IDisposable

@if (cat.IsMeowing)
{
  <div>Cat is meowing!!!</div>
}
<button @onclick="() => cat.Meow()" title="Poke the cat">Poke the cat</button>
@code {


    public Feline cat = new Feline();
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        cat.UpdateState += UpdateState;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        cat.UpdateState -= UpdateState;
    }

    private void UpdateState()
    {
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
}
```

Feline.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Feline
{

    public Action UpdateState = null;

    public bool IsMeowing {get; set;} = false;
    
    public void Meow()
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(3000); // Cat takes a deep breath
            IsMeowing = true; // MEOW!!!!!!!
            if(UpdateState != null)
                UpdateState();
        });
    }
}
```

Example:
https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/cHOGmxPu44pZTDEm38

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This doesn't look thread-safe.

Comment: Doing a callback to `StateHasChanged()` works but you have to wrap it to avoid Thread context issues: `var Cat = new Cat(() => InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged));` then you can call that within the cat to update the state. Works a treat! Thanks!

Comment: I edited the answer to fix the thread-safety.

Answer (score 1):

Blazor does not 'detect variable change' at all.

But you can easily use the async rendering logic:

```
//public void Meow()
  public Task Meow()
  {
     Task t1 = ShowMeow();
     Task t2 = longRunningTask(); // or t2 = Task.Run(longRunningTask)
     await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
  }

  private Task ShowMeow()
  {
     await Task.Delay(3000); // Cat takes a deep breath
     IsMeowing = true; // MEOW!!!!!!!
  }
```

When longRunningTask() executes (mostly) synchronous then use Task.Run(), on Blazor-server only.

Comment: The problem is that I want to use my class in a reusable fashion, so I simply do `timer.Start()` and `timer.Stop()` around my long running task. It would work fine if blazor noticed the variable had changed, but it does not notice unless I call `StateHasChanged();` which is not possible externally. This appears to be because it's changing on a separate thread.

Comment: You will need a UI component, either a Callback or a wrapper. The above is a rough sketch for a wrapper where you can plug the longRunningTask in.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't think either answer provides a full explanation here's mine.

You have not shown everything, but I'm guessing this represents a minimal reproducable example of your code.

```
public class Cat
{
    public bool IsMeowing { get; set; } = false;

    // This is a sync method trying to call async stuff
    public void Meow()
    {
        // No awaiting so no one knows when it's finished
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(3000); // Cat takes a deep breath
            // Not thread safe - updating something that is potentially on another thread
            IsMeowing = true; // MEOW!!!!!!!
        });
    }
}
```

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

@if(this.cat.IsMeowing)
{
    <div class="alert alert-info">
        Meow!!!
    </div>
}

<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick=ProdCat>Prod Cat</button>
</div>

@code {
    private Cat cat = new();

    // No awaiting so runs to completion before the Task completes.
    private void ProdCat()
    {
        cat.Meow();
    }
}
```

Here is what I think you are trying to achieve:

```cs
public class Cat
{
    public bool IsMeowing { get; set; } = false;

    // Async and awaited all the way
    public async Task MeowAsync()
    {
        // Now Updating the variable safely
        IsMeowing = await Task.Run(MeowTask);
    }

    // encapsulates the long running task and returns a bool - what you want to update
    public async Task<bool> MeowTask()
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000); // Cat takes a deep breath
        return true;
    }
}
```

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

@if(this.cat.IsMeowing)
{
    <div class="alert alert-info">
        Meow!!!
    </div>
}

<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-success" disabled="@this.prodding" @onclick=ProdCatAsync>Prod Cat</button>
</div>

@code {
    private Cat cat = new();
    private bool prodding = false;

    private async Task ProdCatAsync()
    {
        prodding = true;
        await cat.MeowAsync();
        prodding = false;
    }
}
```

The key points to note are:

1. `Async` all the way - The button Click is async `MeowAsync` is async yet in your code you tried to turn it into sync code.
2. No Awaiting.

You can't expect the UI to know something has changed without a notification mechanism.  You either code an event based notification system or await Task completion correctly.

By awaiting the button click (and returning a Task to the UI handler) the UI Handler calls `StateHasChanged` on the first await (it's what also updates the button to disabled) and then runs StateHasChanged when everything completes. `cat.IsMeowing` is true so displays the alert and prodding is false, so the button is no longer disabled.

For your long running task you can do something like this:

```cs
public class TaskRunner
{
    public bool IsLongRunning { get; set; } = false;
    public Task LongRunningTask { get; private set; } = Task.CompletedTask;
    public Task ThreeSecondTask { get; private set; } = Task.CompletedTask;

    public int TimeToWait { get; set; } = 3000;

    public Func<Task> TaskToRun = async () => { await Task.Delay(6000); };

    public async Task RunAsync()
    {
        var okToRun = LongRunningTask == Task.CompletedTask
            && ThreeSecondTask == Task.CompletedTask;

        if (!okToRun)
            return;

        var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource();

        this.LongRunningTask = this.RunLongTask();
        this.ThreeSecondTask = Task.Delay(this.TimeToWait, cancel.Token);

        await Task.WhenAny(new Task[] { this.LongRunningTask, this.ThreeSecondTask });

        if (this.ThreeSecondTask.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        {
            IsLongRunning = true;
            return;
        }

        cancel.Cancel();
        return;
    }

    public async Task RunLongTask()
    {
        await Task.Run(this.TaskToRun);
        IsLongRunning = false;
    }
}
```

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

@if (this.testTask.IsLongRunning)
{
    <div class="alert alert-info">
        It s taking a while..
    </div>
}

<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-dark" disabled="@this.running" @onclick=DoAsync>Run Task</button>
</div>

@code {
    private bool running = false;
    private TaskRunner testTask = new();

    private async Task DoAsync()
    {
        running = true;
        await testTask.RunAsync();

        var shouldAwaitTask = testTask.LongRunningTask.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion 
            && testTask.LongRunningTask.Status != TaskStatus.Canceled;

        if (shouldAwaitTask)
        {
            this.StateHasChanged();
            await testTask.LongRunningTask;
        }
        running = false;
    }
}
```