# C# Blazor reversed binding

Tags: c#, frontend, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have the following code:

```
<AddStudents @bind-Students="studentsToAddToClass"/>


@code
{
    private ICollection<Student> studentsToAddToClass { get; set; }
}
```

This binding seems to set the Students collection within the AddStudents component to the value in the code block below (`null`).
However, I want it to work in reverse.
I.e to set `studentsToAddToClass` to the value of `Students` which is initialised within the component itself.

This is my first try at bindings to I may be going about this the complete wrong way also.

I originally tried using `Students` as a parameter then I tried bindings and the only other way I could think was by having a reference to the component within the `@code` block but that seems to be overcomplicating what should be a simple task.

Every way I tried it resulted in `studentsToAddToClass` being assigned to `null`.

Answer (score 2):

You are not implementing binding correctly.

Binding is a two way process.  You need both a  parameter to set and a parameter to pass the changed value back.

Here's a simple *MyComponent.razor* that implements binding.

1. `Students` is the receiving parameter: we don't do anything with it here.
2. `StudentsChanged` is the event callback to pass the value back to the caller. We call it from the button.

```cs
<div class="m-2 p-2">

    <h3>MyComponent</h3>
    <div class="m-2">
        <button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick=this.OnClick>Update</button>
    </div>

</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public IEnumerable<string>? Students { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<IEnumerable<string>> StudentsChanged { get; set; }

    private List<string> _students = new() { "Fred", "Shaun" };
    
    private Task OnClick()
        => this.StudentsChanged.InvokeAsync(_students);
}
```

And then a simple page to demonstrate two different ways of using the component and linking into the binding parameters.

````cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<MyComponent @bind-Students=_students />

<MyComponent StudentsChanged=this.OnStudentsUpdated />

<div class="alert alert-info">
    @(_students?.Count().ToString() ?? "No Students") 
</div>

@code {
    private IEnumerable<string>? _students;

    private Task OnStudentsUpdated(IEnumerable<string> items)
    {
        _students = items;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}```
````

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you implement `OnClick` the way you did instead of implementing it as an `async Task` and then `await this.StudentsChanged.InvokeAsync(_students);`? That would eliminate the need for a `return`.

Comment: It depends on whether you want to "fire and forget" or `await` the update.  If you await, then the button click action, and the UI update associated with it's completion, only happens once the call back code in the parent also completes.  If you "fire and forget" then the click action code complete on the first yield from the call back code.  I've updated the answer because the fallback position should not be "fire and forget".  There are issues with what is known as the `async void` pattern aka "fire and forget".  In my revised bit of code, I return the Task provided by the call back.

Comment: There's an answer here that demonstrates the principle problem - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75758140/13065781.